# Different transition for active and release button

Tags: html, css

I want to make different color transitions when someone clicks the button and releases again.

As you can see below, when you click the button, the color is instant but when you release it, it's not instant. How can I do this?

```css
.submitBtn {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 225px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 3px solid #1c215e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #9fa6fc;
    background-color: #1c215e;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    transition: color 1s, background-color 1s;
}

.submitBtn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #4a53c2;
}

.submitBtn:active {
    color: #3e46a8;
    border-color: #3e46a8;
    transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button class="submitBtn" type="submit">Login</button>
```

Comment: An instant change is not a transition. Just remove it.

Comment: @Paulie_D What should I remove? The transition? But I want to have the transition for the color on `:hover` but not on `:active`.

Comment: _"I also want the transition on both ways"_ - but that's what it already does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick using `text-shadow` that will replace the main color on hover and default state and for the active you use `color` with no transition:

```css
.submitBtn {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  
  border: 3px solid #1c215e;
  color: #0000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 #9fa6fc;
  background-color: #1c215e;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: text-shadow 1s, background-color 1s;
}

.submitBtn:hover {
  background-color: #4a53c2;
  text-shadow: 0 0 black;
}

.submitBtn:active {
  color: red;
  border-color: #3e46a8;
}
```

```html
<button class="submitBtn" type="submit">Login</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that, but as you can see, after clicking there's a transition.

Comment: @goeadli check the update

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. But is it possible without this "work around" with the text shadow? I mean if you zoom in you can see the text shadow.

Comment: @goeadli you can wait for more answers

Comment: Is the color `#0000` equal to `transparent`?

Comment: @goeadli yes it's transparent